# Do I need captcha public key and/or private key for localhost?

Tags: php, recaptcha, public-key, private-key

I am developing locally with PHP on Xampp.

I am trying to use [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/).

Do I need public and/or private key?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use reCAPTCHA, you need [a public/private API key **pair**](http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/client.html).

Using the [PHP Library](http://recaptcha.net/plugins/php/), to display the CAPTCHA:

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "..."; // you got this from the signup page
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

and then to verify:

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "...";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
```

Comment: its give me error message like    Go back and try it again.(reCAPTCHA said: invalid-site-private-key)